# c# - Convert number in string to have certain number of digits

Tags: c#, string, formatting, type-conversion

I have a number in string format. This number will be between 1-6 digits and i need to convert it to be filled with zeroes on left side in order to always be 6 digit number. Is there any more efficient way than this?

```
Int32.Parse("5").ToString("D6")
```

Conversion to int just feels a bit unnecessary.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by more efficient?

Comment: i suppose "000005" is out of the question?

Comment: @MongZhu skip conversion to int and back and just format the string as is done in accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`String.PadLeft`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string result = number.PadLeft(6, '0');
```

If the number can be negative this doesn't work and you need your `int.Parse` approach.

Answer (score 1):

It is unnecessary

```
string result = "5".PadLeft(6,'0');
```

Answer (score -1):

string someText = "test 5 rate";

someText = Regex.Replace(someText, @"\d+", n => n.Value.PadLeft(5, '0'));